# How does IE work with contentless anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a hover over effect on an image on a site that I am working on. I am having two problems with this. The first is browser specific and is my main worry.

**Anchor tag problem:**

When I view the site on Chrome, Safari and Firefox the tooltip ([Jquery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools)) works as expected. When viewed IE, the hover over is really strange. It seems as though the hover only is recognized when your mouse is over the outermost row of pixels (the border) on the anchor tag. The result is not being able to view the tool tip while in Internet Explorer. I have tried doing this in ways other than with Jquery tools, but even with the HTML event "onmouseover", the same effect happens.

I tried a few things while experimenting with this, and it seems that if I put something inside the anchor tag like some text, the text expands the hoverable area. This is interesting because this only happens in internet explorer.

For my environment, I am running on a 27" monitor with the latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer 8 to test for compatibility.

**Second z-index problem:**

The second problem I am having is with the tooltip. It seems as though the tooltip, although styled with the highest z-index, goes behind an image of a school that I have infront of it. I figured that one of you might have a clue on what is going on with that, because I am stumped.

**View the site**

I put the site up and minimized it on jsfiddle.com. Here is the link to the project that I posted.

http://jsfiddle.net/keirp/B9Cgc/

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<a>` some dimensions and/or display block or inline block. IE has trouble getting position for `<a>` when they are inline with nothing in them

Comment: I did that just now, but it doesn't seem to fix it. I already have dimensions on the link's inline styles.